# How to organize JSON to hierarch in Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON-structure:

```
[  
  {
    "artist": "Jim",
    "nationality": "English",
    "album": "Hello!",
    "year": "2020",
    "label": "Mercury"
  },
  {
    "artist": "SoundDog",
    "nationality": "USA",
    "album": "SoundDog",
    "year": "2018",
    "label": "Private"
  },
  {
    "artist": "Jim",
    "nationality": "English",
    "album": "Wait here",
    "year": "2012",
    "label": "PrivateLabel"
  }
]
```

And I would like to get it formatted to the following structure:

```
[{
        "artist": "Jim",
        "nationality": "English",
        "albums": [{
                "album": "Hello!",
                "year": "2020",
                "label": "Mercury"
            }, {
                "album": "Wait here",
                "year": "2012",
                "label": "PrivateLabel"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "artist": "SoundDog",
        "nationality": "USA",
        "albums": [{
                "album": "SoundDog",
                "year": "2018",
                "label": "Private"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've been playing with some for-loops but am baffled how to do it in a nice and working way?

I created this short function to find albums and construct the list but I should call it only once per artist. How can I achieve that?

```
def get_albums(artist):
    albums = []
    for j in data:      # data = original JSON
        if j['artist'] == artist:
            album = {'album': j['album'], 'year': j['year'], 'label': j['label']}
            albums.append(album)
    return albums
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a dictionary with `artist` as key. Building such dictionary is not particularly complicated: you walk through the albums and if it contains an artist already, you append the album to their `albums`, otherwise you add the artist, and the current album as first one in the list:

```
org = [...]  # your original data
artists = {} # the empty dict
for album in org:
  album = album.copy()
  artist = album["artist"]
  if artist in artists:
    artists[artist]["albums"].append(album)
  else:
    artists[artist] = {"artist":album["artist"], "nationality":album["nationality"], "albums":[album]}
  del album["artist"]
  del album["nationality"]
print(list(artists.values()))    # this is structure you asked for actually
print(artists["Jim"]["albums"])  # getting albums for Jim
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be better to store the data as:

```
{
  "Jim" : {
    "nationality": "English",
    "albums": [
      ...
    ]
  },
  "SoundDog" : {
    "nationality": "USA",
    "albums": [
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Then, retrieval by artist become a trivial operation.

Comment: Fair enough, how that would happen then?